# Creating VMs using chef

Tags: chef-infra, virtual-machine, bootstrapping, esx

I am totally new to Chef and have very less knowledge about it. I have my chef server and workstation configured. I have chef-client installed in a node. I want to create cookbooks or recipes that can create,delete and manage VMs in another ESX server whose information i have. Please let me know if it is possible using chef and if yes please let me now where i can get help regarding this.

I have got articles earlier where i can create VMs and using knife, bootstrap them and then manage them. But, I don't want my workstation to directly interact with the VMs and rather interact with the chef node where I have installed chef-client already to invoke VMs and manage them through the recipe or cookbook scripts.Let me know if that's possible in any way.

TIA

Answer (score 3):

There is a project called chef-provisioning to interface with VM management APIs, but I would highly recommend using Hashicorp Terraform instead. It does mean using two different tools, but Terraform is enough of an improvement over the functionality of chef-provisioning that it is warranted.